# How to handle onChange in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, tsx

I am new to Typescript. How do you normally handle `onChange` in `TextField`, when using Typescript language?

- The function `handleChangeDate(e: React.ChangeEvent<any>)` in the code below works, but I get warnings because I use the type `any`. Which other way can I write this code?

---

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { TextField } from '@material-ui/core';

const [date, setDate] = useState(
    new Date().getDate() + '/' + (new Date().getMonth() + 1) + '/' + new Date().getFullYear(),
);

const handleChangeDate = (e: React.ChangeEvent<any>): void => {
    setDate(e.target.value);
};
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

For MUI TextField (v5.10.11)

```
event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement | HTMLInputElement>
```

Comment: I get the following error: `TS2345: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction '.`

Comment: @Mees Works fine in my case; the error is likely not related to `event`, but with this: [How can I define type for setState when React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>> not accepted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65823778/how-can-i-define-type-for-setstate-when-react-dispatchreact-setstateactionstri)