# typescript - Is there a way to output the long date from datapicker

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript

In typescript, in this date-picker, after selecting a date from the calendar, the selected date is outputted in the format dd-mm-yy, is there a way to output the date in the long format(Wednesday 9th March 2022.) This is using the standard datepicker.

```
<input type="date" onChange={
(event:React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) =>{
let newTimesheet = [...timesheet];
newTimesheet[index].date=event.target.value;
setTimesheet(newTimesheet);
}
}/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
setTimesheet(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB', { dateStyle: 'full' }).format(newTimesheet));
```

i hope it works!

Comment: There is an error because " Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<TimesheetRow[]>'  "Any guidance on how to sort this. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65823778/how-can-i-define-typescript-type-for-a-setstate-function-when-react-dispatchrea) helps you

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily via `Intl` although the formatting is not the same as yours:

```
new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-US", { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' }).format(date); // Wednesday, March 9, 2022
```

[`Intl` Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl)